# Force remained text onto next line

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make textWidget1 wrap its `remained text` to the next line in a row.

like below :
[image]

how can I achieve this?

Using `Wrap` make the entire `textWidget1`to next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by drawing them.

Answer (score 1):

you may use triple quotes like in the following example:

```
Container(
      child: Text(
        '''Text1
        Text2 
        ''',
        maxLines: 3,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
```

Run the above code on DartPad.

Hope I could help you.
Luis

Comment: thanks luis for you help, but there is a container middle of two text widget, and the last one should take remained text to next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Text` inside a `Container` and the container wrapped by `Flexible`.

Comment: its three widget inside the row, wrapping them with flexible not going to make last text widget to send remaind text onto next line